# Why can't I start java directly using Gradles Exec-task?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I wanted to start java from a gradle build-script using the Exec-task (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

Using the command `java -version` directly does not work.

```
task runApp(type:Exec) {
  commandLine 'java -version'
}
```

When copying the command to a file named `script.sh`, it is executed

```
task runApp(type:Exec) {
  commandLine './script.sh'
}
```

But why? Shouldn't `commandLine 'java -version'` work as well?

Comment: Try splitting out the parameters into separate strings like so: `commandLine 'java', '-version'`

Comment: You should also look into JavaExec to run Java from gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: @RaGe: It really seemed to be the spaces,... Please write an answer, so I can accept it,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the examples on the documentation page show the commandline command broken out into comma separated strings with no spaces in them. I would try:

```
task runApp(type:Exec) {
  commandLine 'java', '-version'
}
```